# How can I notify the user if the current iPhone/iPad app become phased out

Tags: iphone, ipad

Suppose I have published an app for iPhone and for iPad, but they are absolutely the same.

I would like to combine this app into one to support both iPhone and iPad. How can I notify the current users (of the iPhone and iPad versions) that their app is phased out, and we have published a new app for both iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't implement any special mechanism for that, then you can't really notify the user about your change. You could release an update for the (old) app telling the user to download the new version, which is compatible for both iPhone and iPad (with an Alertview for example) and provide the link to the new app.

Comment: You might want replace the iPhone version of your app with the universal one, then you'd only have to direct the iPad users to your new app.